# Apache timeout in perl CGI tool

Tags: apache, perl, timeout, cgi

I am running a Perl CGI tool that executes a system command (Unix) which may run for a few seconds up to an hour.
After the script is finished, the tool should display the results log on the screen (in a browser).
The problem is that after about 5 minutes I get a timeout message "Gateway Time-out" - the system command continue to run but I'm unable to display to the user the results of the run.

In the Apache config file (httpd.conf): Timeout 300.

Is there a **simple** way ordering the Apache to increase the timeout only for a specific run?
I don't really want to change the Apache timeout permanently (or should I?) and not dramatically update the code (a lot of regression tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the script generate some output every once in a while. The timeout is not for running the program to completion, but is a timeout while Apache is waiting for data. So if you manage to get your program to output something regularly while running, you will be fine.

Note that HTTP clients, i.e. browsers, also have their own timeout. If your browser does not get any new data from the web server five minutes (typically), the browser will declare a timeout and give up even if the server is still processing. If your long running processing gives some output every now and then, it will help against browser timeouts too!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

Though the accepted answer is the best (it's variously known as KeepAlive packets in TCP/IP, or Tickle packets way back in appletalk days) you did ask if you can do dynamic Apache config.

An apache module could do this.  Oh, but that's a pain to write in C.
Remember that mod_perl (and to some extent mod_python, though it's deprecated) do not only handlers but wrap the internal config in perl as well.  You could write something complicated to increase the timeout in certain situations.  But, this would be a bear to write and test, and you're better off doing what Krisku says.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way to specify a timeout on the `<!--#include virtual=... -->` directive, but if you use mod_cgid instead of mod_cgi then starting with Apache 2.4.10 there's a configurable timeout parameter available which you can specify in httpd.conf or .htaccess:

`CGIDScriptTimeout` *nnn*s

...where *nnn* is the number of seconds that Apache will allow a cogitating CGI script to continue to run.

*Caveat:* If you use PHP with Apache, then your Apache is presumably configured in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf to use "prefork" MPM (because PHP requires it unless built with thread-safe flags), and the default Apache installation used mod_cgi with the prefork MPM, so you'll probably need to edit /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-cgi.conf to tell Apache to use mod_cgid instead of mod_cgi.

Although the comment in 01-cgi.conf says, *"mod_cgid should be used with a threaded MPM; mod_cgi with the prefork MPM,"* that doesn't seem to be correct, because mod_cgid seems to work fine with prefork MPM and PHP, for me, with Apache 2.4.46.

Although that doesn't give you complete control over server timeouts, you could specify a different CGIDScriptTimeout setting for a particular directory (e.g., put your slow .cgi files in the ./slowstuff/ folder).

(Of course, as krisku mentioned in the accepted answer, changing CGIDScriptTimeout won't solve the problem of the user's web browser timing out.)